# What does "shoot somebody a smile" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

Is it like the expression *"shoot somebody a glance"* in that it means *to smile at someone briefly*? I couldn't really find a dictionary explanation, but I've definitely seen the phrase before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include specific references (links would be good) to the dictionaries you looked in to avoid having this question get closed.

Comment: like in "some enchanted evening"?

Answer (score 1):

***[To shoot:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shoot://)***

> to direct suddenly or swiftly:
>
> - Shoot the spotlight on the doorway. *He shot a smile at his wife.*

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

[to cast](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/cast_1)

> a look/glance/smile [transitive] cast (somebody) something to look,
>   smile, etc. in a particular direction. "She cast a welcoming smile in
>   his direction."

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to the phrase "flash a smile" which compares a smile to a photograph or beam of light that triggers positive response from the target, except “shoot somebody a smile” includes an aiming component that will sometimes imply the ability to stun/paralyze/["smite"-slang] the target.

Answer (score 0):

The association of ideas is with gunfire.

If a firearm is discharged, the firing of a single shot is an extremely brief event. *Shooting a smile at someone* is a way of saying that the smile has an equally brief duration -- and often is used to suggest that it may have also an equally great impact (although not in a literal sense).